# Solving $\sqrt{6x-y^2-4z+1}-\sqrt{y+4z^2}=\sqrt{9x^2+y+4}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing, systems-of-equations

> Solve over reals:
>
> $$\sqrt{6x-y^2-4z+1}-\sqrt{y+4z^2}=\sqrt{9x^2+y+4}$$

I tried squaring

$$6x-y^2-4z+1+4z^2-2\sqrt{(6x-y^2-4z+1)(y+4z^2)}=9x^2+4$$

or

$$(2z-1)^2-y^2=3+(3x-1)^2+2\sqrt{(6x-y^2-4z+1)(y+4z^2)}$$

But this does not seem to be leading anywhere.

Comment: What do you mean, "solve"?  Solve for all three variables?  With only one equation, you might have an underdetermination problem.

Comment: It  seems you can take the $3+(3x-1)^2$ to the other side again and you will get a fourth order polynomial (you will still have to check the sign for all infinitely many solutions you get)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have: $$6x-y^2-4z+1=y+4z^2+9x^2+y+4+2\sqrt{(y+4z^2)(9x^2+y+4)}$$ or
$$(3x-1)^2+(y+1)^2+(2z+1)^2+2\sqrt{(y+4z^2)(9x^2+y+4)}=0.$$
Thus, we obtain the following system:
$$3x-1=y+1=2z+1=(y+4z^2)(9x^2+y+4)=0.$$
Can you end it now?

Comment: Yes $(x,y,z)=(1/3,-1,-1/2)$. Thanks.